# Настройка админ-панели Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

Мне нужно сделать отображение одного ForeignKey поля в зависимости от другого.

У меня есть модель Player (игрок) с ForeignKey полями clan (клан игрока), ссылающимся на модель Clan,  и clan_pos (должность игрока в выбранном клане clan), ссылающимся на модель ClanPosition.

У модели ClanPosition есть ForeignKey поле clan - тот клан, к которому относится данный пост. Соответственно посты всех кланов относятся к одной модели - лежат в одной бд.

В админ-панели Django поле ForeignKey имеет тип 'select' - при создании нового объекта Player, чтобы выбрать у него поле clan(клан создающегося игрока) нужно нажать на соответствующюю строку и в выезжающем списке выбрать нужный объект Clan(т.к. это ForeignKey поле, ссылающееся на модель Clan). После этого таким же образом нужно выбрать clan_pos(ForeignKey, ссылающийся на модель ClanPosition) - пост игрока в ЭТОМ(выбранном выше) клане (ведь в модели ClanPosition у нас посты ВСЕХ кланов)

Так вот, мне нужно, чтобы при выборе клана игрока в выезжающем списке для выбора поста в клане оставалось только те посты (ClanPosition), у которых поле clan(ForeignKey, ссылающееся на модель Clan) является тем кланом, который игрок выбрал выше, в поле Clana игрока.

Логично, ведь если мы выбрали клан для игрока, то пост должен относиться к ЭТОМУ клану. То есть, если мы выбрали для игрока клан CPRF, то в вариантах из выпадающего списка следующего поля clan_pos должны остаться только те ClanPosition, у которых clan - это выше выбранный CPRF

Ещё более общо: я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при выборе одной модели в ForeignKey поле модели, у другого поля этой модели оставались только те варианты(модели), у которых нужное ForeignKey поле ссылается на ту же модель которую мы выбрали

Привожу пример того, что я хочу сделать:

```
class Clan(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield(args=something)

class ClanPosition(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield(args=something)
    # клан, к которому относится данный пост
    clan = models.ForeignKey(Clan, args=something)

class Player(models.Model):
    nickname = models.Charfield(args=something)
    # Клан игрока. При выборе в админ-панели 
    # появляется список со всеми кланами - объектами класса Clan
    clan = models.ForeignKey(Clan)
    # Надо что-то такое - список для выбора 
    # определенных постов в зависимости от 
    # выбранного ранее клана игрока
    # Но нижестоящая строка выдает ошибку
    pos_choices = [(pos, pos.title) for pos in ClanPosition.objects.filter(clan=clan)]
    # Определяем поле для выбора поста в выше выбранном клане.
    # Пытаюсь разрешить выбирать только те посты (ClanPosition),
    # которые относятся к клану, выбранному выше с помощью реально существующего
    # в Django аргумента choices
    clan_pos = models.ForeignKey(ClanPosition, choices=pos_choices, some_other_args=other_args)
```

То есть я хочу, чтобы при выборе клана в следующем поле оставались только посты, относящиеся к этому клану.

Как возможно реализовать такую настройку для полей в админ-панели Django? Если есть какие-либо вопросы - готов уточнить, чего я хочу добиться. Постарался изложить все как можно понятнее.

Answer (score 1):

Это делается в модуле `admin.py`, в методе `formfield_for_foreignkey` соответствующего класса, отнаследованного от `admin.ModelAdmin`. Посмотрите [пример](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) в документации.

Comment: Большое спасибо за огромную помощь в решении. Я только не пойму, как внутри этого метода узнать значение поля, в зависимости от которого внутри данной функции нужно изменить queryset. В вашем примере из документации фильтрация происходит по авторству в этих записях пользователя, а мне нужно отфильтровать в зависимости от другого поля этой модели. Не знаете как обратиться к другому полю этой же модели внутри этой функции? В данный момент нет под рукой ноутбука, скоро буду разбираться в этом направлении подробнее

Comment: Очевидно, в вашем случае db_field.name -это будет 'clan'. Рекомендую поставить в этот метод точку останова (breakpoint) и в отладчике посмотреть, что туда прилетает.